# Exercise from set theory

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know how I may use the sets algebra in this problem
I need someone help me, in the following exercise, prove that:

$$ (A \cup X = A \cup Y) \wedge (A \cap X = A\cap Y) \Leftrightarrow X=Y $$

best regards

Comment: Is the statement supposed to hold for all sets $A$?

Comment: yes, I need to prove that is true for all arbitrary sets A,X,Y.

Comment: @PabloHerrera : Your comment makes it look as if you misunderstood wckronholm's question.  The question was whether for a particular pair of sets $X,Y$ the "iff" holds for every $A$, NOT whether the whole statement holds for every triple of sets $A,X,Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication in the $\Longleftarrow$ direction is obvious.

For the other direction, assume $X \neq Y$. Then there exist a point $p$ that is in one and not the other. We can without loss of generality assume that $p\in X$ but $p\notin Y$.

Now, if $p \in A$, then $p \in A\cap X$ but $p\notin A\cap Y$, so the intersections are unequal. If $p\notin A$, then $p\in A\cup X$, but $p\notin A\cup Y$. In either case either the unions are unequal or the intersections are unequal, and we have the result by contrapositivity (modus tollens).

Comment: Wonderful thanks a lot!!

Comment: Or just take $A = \varnothing$ for the non-obvious implication.

Comment: @wckronholm It's supposed to work for _any_ $A$.

Comment: If you assume that it works for all $ A $ then in particular it works if $ A $ is the empty set.

Comment: @wckronholm The goal is not to prove that there exists an $A$ that makes the equivalence hold. We have to prove that the equivalence holds _no matter_ what $A$ is.

Comment: @Arthur This is what I was trying to get the OP to clarify. Is the statement 
$\forall X, Y, A\; ((A \cup X = A \cup Y) \wedge (A \cap X = A\cap Y) \Leftrightarrow X=Y)$ 
or
$\forall X, Y \; (\forall A (A \cup X = A \cup Y) \wedge (A \cap X = A\cap Y) \Leftrightarrow X=Y)$

Answer (score 2):

First, suppose that $A\cup X=A\cup Y$ and $A\cap X=A\cap Y$.

Statement: $X\subset Y$. Indeed, if $x\in X$ then $x\in X\subset A\cup X=A\cup Y$, and so
$$x\in A \text{  or  } x\in Y .$$ 
If $x\in Y$, then we concluse the statement, but if $x\in A$, then as by assumption we have $x\in X$, we concluse that $x\in A\cap X=A\cap Y$, then $x\in Y$.

In any case it follows that $x\in Y$, i.e. we concluse that $X\subset Y$.

Analogously we proof that $Y\subset X$. Then, we obtain that $X=Y$.

The converse is trivial.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty direct proof:
$$X\setminus A=(X\cup A)\setminus A=(Y\cup A)\setminus A=Y\setminus A$$
Therefore

$$X=(X\setminus A)\cup(X\cap A)=(Y\setminus A)\cup(Y\cap A)=Y$$

The other implication is trivial.